# Query to pick departments

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below:

```
Dept: 

DeptName    State      Country
D1          Paris      France
D2          Lyon       France
D3          Lille      France


Employee:
EmployeeId      EmployeeName     DeptName 
1               John               D1
2               Diesel             D2
3               Rock               D2
4               John               D1
5               Diesel             D2
6               Karn               D2
7               Triple             D1
8               Nancy              D3
9               Greg               D3
```

Output:

```
DeptName    CountOfDifferentEmployeeName
D3          2
```

Get the department name and count of unique employee names for department using following conditions:

1. Pick only those department which have unique employee names in their country.There should not be same employee name in department in same country
2. While counting, avoid counting repeated employee names for the same department

But I am confused with whether I should do group by country and zoo name and how do I pick zoo name satisfying condition 1.

```
select * from Dept d
inner join Employee e on d.DeptName  = e.DeptName
group by
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gather you want the names of department that don't have repeated employee name. If that is the case the query below is one way you can do it:

--1 Get per country all department that have repeated employee names

--2 Get the count per country and department of unique employee excluding the county department list in the cte

```
with Dept as 
(          
select 'D1'  as DeptName,        'Paris'  as State   , 'France' as Country
union select 'D2'  ,        'Lyon'   ,    'France'
union select 'D3'   ,       'Lille'  ,    'France'
),

Employee as 
(                 
select 1  as EmployeeId     ,        'John'   as EmployeeName      ,      'D1' as DeptName
union select 2 ,              'Diesel' ,            'D2'
union select 3  ,             'Rock'    ,           'D2'
union select 4   ,            'John'     ,          'D1'
union select 5    ,           'Diesel'    ,         'D2'
union select 6     ,          'Karn'       ,        'D2'
union select 7      ,         'Triple'      ,       'D1'
union select 8       ,        'Nancy'        ,      'D3'
union select 9        ,       'Greg'          ,     'D3'
)

select d.DeptName, d.Country, count(*) as unique_employee_names
from Dept d
inner join Employee e on d.DeptName = e.DeptName
where not exists
(
  select 1 
  from (

        select d.DeptName, d.Country
        from Dept d
        inner join Employee e on d.DeptName = e.DeptName
        group by d.DeptName, d.Country, e.EmployeeName
        having count(*) > 1

       ) c where d.DeptName = c.DeptName and d.Country = c.Country
 )
group by d.DeptName, d.Country
```

Ouput is:

```
DeptName    Country   unique_employee_names
D3          France    2
```

[image]

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me but i am not getting any department names with this query. In my question I want to avoid duplication with in the same countries of department so dont you think we should include group by country and state as well?

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer so can get the  unique employee names per department

Comment: Thanks but the thing is I have alot of countries in my database which I have not included in my question to keep the question short.

Comment: Adjusted the answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks but still getting blank result sorry

Comment: Hi, I have changed my answer to add the data for the sample you sent ILoveSO, and I have the output you showed in your question. You can copy the entire code to test. You cannot get blank result. I have added an image too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207799/discussion-between-ilovestackoverflow-and-zip).

Answer (score 2):

If I get your requirement correct, this following script will help you to achieve your desired output-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f73a617f575dbb25ab47cf41deb4ac12)

```
SELECT D.DeptName,D.Country,
COUNT(E.EmployeeName) CountOfDifferentEmployeeName
FROM Employee E
iNNER JOIN Dept D ON E.DeptName = D.DeptName
GROUP BY D.DeptName,D.Country
HAVING COUNT(E.EmployeeName) = COUNT(DISTINCT E.EmployeeName)
```